# Change origin name in Axios post request in Next js

Tags: next.js, axios, request

I want to change origin name like `bookshop.webmanza.com` in axios request header. I pass my code this way like,

```
const customOrigin = "bookshop.webmanza.com";

export const http = Axios.create({
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    Origin: customOrigin,
  },
});
```

Request header screenshot,
[image]

but unfortunately, always its redirect to `http://localhost:3000`, but interestingly postman has been called this api when i pass origin in request header.  its don't override. For your kind information, i'm using **next js 13** and API has been called in root level component like `Layout.tsx` file, my OS is **linux(ubuntu 20.4)**

Give me proper answer to solve this issue, i would like to highly appreciate it.

I will expect this type response,
[image]